# Can I use one dependency for another dependency in MultiProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Can I use one dependency for another dependency in MultiProvider?

I tried like this, but it didn't work:

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: <Provider<dynamic>>[
        Provider<SettingsProvider>.value(value: SettingsProvider()),
        Provider<Bloc>.value(value: Bloc(Provider.of<SettingsProvider>(context))),
      ]),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => Auth()),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Messages>(
      builder: (context, auth, previousMessages) => Messages(auth),
      initialBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Messages(null),
    ),
```

use  one provider inside other provider

```
class Messages extends ChangeNotifier {
final Auth _authProvider;

List<Message> _messages = [];
List<Message> get messages => _messages;

Messages(this._authProvider) {
    if (this._authProvider != null) {
        if (_authProvider.loggedIn) fetchMessages();
    }
}

...
```

}